# How to transform a time series pandas dataframe using the index attributes?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

Given a dataframe with time series that looks like this:

```
                      Close
2015-02-20 14:00:00  1200.1
2015-02-20 14:10:00  1199.8
2015-02-21 14:00:00  1199.3
2015-02-21 14:10:00  1199.0
2015-02-22 14:00:00  1198.4
2015-02-22 14:10:00  1199.7
```

How can I apply a function that transforms it into a dataframe like this:

```
          '14:00' '14:10'
2015-02-20 1200.1 1199.8
2015-02-21 1199.3 1199.0
2015-02-22 1198.4 1199.7
```

Note: This is a simplified example. The actual dataframe has many days and all the intraday minutes too. So it would be useful if it is an efficient procedure.

Thanks

Comment: In your sample data you only have observations for 14:00 and 14:10 on 2015-02-20, shouldn't your horizontal axis have 6 fields?

Comment: You are right. It's a typo. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pivot on the `date` and `time` components of the index:

Create the frame:

```
i =pd.to_datetime(['2015-02-20 14:00:00','2015-02-20 14:10:00','2015-02-21 14:20:00'\
               ,'2015-02-21 14:30:00','2015-02-22 14:40:00','2015-02-22 14:50:00'])
df =pd.DataFrame(index=i, data={'Close':[1200.1,1199.8,1199.3,1199.0,1198.4,1199.7]})
```

pivot:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index= df.index.date, columns=df.index.time, values = 'Close')
```

returns:

```
          14:00:00  14:10:00    14:20:00    14:30:00    14:40:00    14:50:00
2015-02-20  1200.1  1199.8      NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-02-21  NaN     NaN         1199.3      1199        NaN         NaN
2015-02-22  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN         1198.4     1199.7
```

use `aggfunc` as an argument of `pivot_table` to determine how data is aggregated if necessary

Comment: How can I modify the df so that I could do calculations like df['14:10:00'] - df['14:00:00']? Thanks. Let me know if I should start a new question with this.

Comment: The new question is here if you would like to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665361/in-pandas-how-can-i-modify-the-format-of-a-pivot-table-columns